# SSIS inserting space in computed variable for "Execute Process Task"

Tags: cmd, ssis, winscp

I'm using SSIS in conjunction with WinSCP to push a file. Everything seemed to be going OK, but I'm getting an error. It looks like SSIS is, at some point, putting a "phantom space" into my variable for some reason.

The variable is set up like this:

```
"/command \"open sftp://" + @[User::SFTP_User]+":"+ @[User::SFTP_Pass] + "@" +  @[User::SFTP_Site] + " -hostkey=\"\"ssh-rsa 2048 "+ @[User::SFTP_Hostkey]  +"\"\"\" \"put -nopreservetime "+  @[User::InventoryFile] + " " +  @[User::PurchaseFile] + " " + @[User::SFTP_Location]  + "\" \"exit\""
```

and is used as the script string for WinSCP.com.

When I take the computed value and copy it into Notepad++, I get something like

```
/command "open sftp://USER:Pas$word@ftp.site.com -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00""" "put -nopreservetime \\my\path\file.csv \\my\path\file2.csv  /remote/path/" "exit"
```

HOWEVER!!! Copying/pasting this to the command line, rather than notepad++, however, yields

```
/command "open sftp://USER: Pas$word@ftp.site.com -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00""" "put -nopreservetime \\my\path\file.csv \\my\path\file2.csv  /remote/path/" "exit"
```

ALSO!!! when I run the package, I get an error message:

> ```
> Error: 0xC0029151 at WinSCP Files to MSA, Execute Process Task: In Executing "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com" "/command "open sftp://USER: Pas$word@ftp.site.com -hostkey=""ssh-rsa 2048 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00""" "put -nopreservetime \\my\path\file.csv \\my\path\file2.csv  /remote/path/" "exit"" at "\\my\working\path\", The process exit code was "1" while the expected was "0".
> ```

Please notice that there is an extra " " (space) in between the "USER:" and the password. This is breaking the command. Also notice that there is an extra space in between the upload files and the upload location (however, this does not seem to have any ill effect). If I copy that whole thing to a command prompt and just remove that space after the colon, it works...

Where are these phantom spaces coming from and/or how do I get rid of them?

Comment: It's probably not a standard space then, otherwise you would get it in Notepad++ too. It's probably some special whitespace (like the null character), which Notepad++ strips.

Comment: I can't see an issue with the command used, although I've adjusted a few spaces myself, `"/command \"open sftp://" + @[User::SFTP_User] + ":" + @[User::SFTP_Pass] + "@" + @[User::SFTP_Site] + " -hostkey=\"\"ssh-rsa 2048 " + @[User::SFTP_Hostkey] + \"\""\" \"put -nopreservetime " + @[User::InventoryFile] + " " + @[User::PurchaseFile] + " " + @[User::SFTP_Location] + "\" \"exit\""`, Therefore I'm in agreement that the space character is most likely some non standard character. I would assume that it's coming from the password, which obviously I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by going into Notepad++ and using the "HEX Editor" plugin to see the hidden characters.

Even "Show all characters" was not showing the hidden characters...

I'm sure that they came from copying from formatted text into the variable. It was really strange that in *some* instances you could copy/paste them without the formatting and in other circumstances the hidden characters would be there. I usually use notepad++ as a tool (intermediate copy/paste) for removing formatting, but it was not removing these devils.

Anyway, once I found the hidden characters in the HEX editor, I was able to simply remove them from there, switch back to ASCII mode, copy the string and paste it back into the SSIS program and go from there. Problem solved!

Thanks all - your ideas helped get me to the solution.